# Getting info for a specific Date and Subtracting two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So this is really more like two questions combined because it's for the same table I'm trying to gather all this info from

**ANSWERED BY TMNT IN COMMENTS** For question one: I'm trying to collect some info based on `MAX` Date. The table contains various SiteID entries with various dates with various amounts of info I want retrieve.  However, I just want to capture just the MOST recent date date for each site and all it's corresponding info.

When writing this below query I get all the right SiteIDs

```
Select
sn.siteID,
MAX(sn.CreationDate)
From SiteNotifications sn
Group By sn.SiteID
Order By sn.SiteID
```

However, as soon as I start writing in the other info I need it's start showing me dates from previous notifications rather than the `MAX` date.

```
Select
sn.siteID,
MAX(sn.CreationDate),
sn.NotificationMessage,
sn.CreatedByUserID
From SiteNotifications sn
Group By sn.SiteID, sn.NotificationMessage, sn.CreatedByUserID
Order By sn.SiteID
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that since there are different users, different notification messages, etc. they'll show up because they're "unique" rows.  But now that `MAX` isn't working I'm totally not sure how to proceed.

**ANSWERED BY LANGE IN COMMENTS** - Second Question: I'm trying to subtract two DateTime times to display the amount of days between them.

I write this

```
Select
DateAdd(d,-mino,maxo)
FROM
(Select 
sn.SiteID,
MAX(sn.CreationDate) Maxo,
MIN(sn.CreationDate) Mino
From SiteNotifications sn
Group By sn.SiteID)a
```

And it gets me an error message that reads

`Operand data type datetime is invalid for minus operator.`

I tried converting the dates by using `CAST` and `CONVERT` but keeps giving me the same problem.  :(

Comment: The error is because you are trying to make a datetime value negative. This doesn't work. Even if it did you would find another syntax error because a datetime is not valid as the second parameter to DATEADD. Try changing to DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, maxo, mino), maxo). This is just a shot in the dark. If you could create a sql fiddle at sqlfiddle.com this would be a LOT easier.

Comment: "However, as soon as I start writing in the other info I need it's start showing me dates from previous notifications rather than the MAX date." - Remember to add the the "other info" to the group by clause as well.

Comment: I'll try it out - but I thought using a negative was OK? Was lurking around here before and noticed someone did that - but perhaps it's dependent on certain programs? (BTW using Management Studio 2012)

Comment: BTW @TMNT2014 Minor edit I had to carry out above with the other info - but adding all of that in the Group By clause doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @SeanLange - and the DateDiff worked - Thanks!

Comment: @StayPuft a negative integer is ok in DATEADD but not a negative date. That code was effectively saying -1 * MyDate. You can't have a negative July 11th. DATEDIFF can return a negative value and that is perfectly valid in a DATEADD. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the First question since you need the max date by site Id irrespective of the other fields  you can change your query to.

```
Select
 sn.siteID,
 MaxCreationDate.Maxo,
 sn.NotificationMessage,
 sn.CreatedByUserID
From SiteNotifications sn
INNER JOIN (SELECT SiteId, MAX(CreationDate)Maxo FROM SiteNotifications GROUP BY SiteId      )MaxCreationDate
 ON MaxCreationDate.SiteID = sn.SiteID AND sn.CreationDate = Maxo
 Group By sn.SiteID, sn.NotificationMessage, sn.CreatedByUserID, MaxCreationDate.Maxo
 Order By sn.SiteID
```

OR use the row_number and partition concept.

```
 WITH CTE AS (
  Select
  siteID,
  CreationDate
  NotificationMessage,
  CreatedByUserID, 
  Row_Number()OVER(Partition by siteID ORDER by CreationDate desc)RN
  From SiteNotifications)
 SELECT * FROM CTE
 WHERE RN =1
```

Comment: Hmm just tried running this - but seems like it's still giving me the non-Max dates still :(

Comment: Does adding the group by in the inner query help? If not can you share some sample data?

Comment: Soo I created a table for sqlfiddle but it seems like I'm having a bit of trouble adding in the info into the table - the DateTime is giving me a truncated data error :\

Comment: Ah wait figured it out - should now be able to run with your query - which I had to fix a bit just so it could run: 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a1d8/1

Comment: Updated the query to add the alias .. looks like adding the group BY solved your issue.

Comment: Ehh not quite - really I just want to see the MAX date info - not the other info as well. IE, there are multiple notificationmessages and status for the same SiteID, rather than just one row of the info with regards to the Max date

Comment: Ahh got you...Updated SQLFiddle and answer with the query.

Comment: Hmm looks like I'm still seeing the same query?